# Bootstrap typeahead not Working inside the Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using codeigniter framework and i am using bootstrap typeahead and all is fine but my problem is when i put it inside the bootstrap modal the bootstrap typeahead will not work. can someone help me? please. this is my code

```
<a data-target="ajaxify" data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo base_url()?>task/add_task" class="no-u quick-task">
    <h4>Task</h4>
    <span>This is a simple description</span>
 </a>
```

and inside my add_task controller i call the view task_view.php and task.js but it seems that the typeahead is not working inside the bootstrap modal.

this is the content of task.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#assign_to").typeahead({
    source: [{value: 'Charlie'}, {value: 'Gudbergur'}]              
});
});
```

this is the content of task_view.php : just a sample.

```
<div id="ajaxx" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
  <!--Your title here -->
  <h3>Modal Heading</h3>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form><input type="text" name="assign_to" id="assign_to" /></form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <!--Your dont change the attributes only the value here -->
  <a href="#" id="n0" class="btn n0" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
  <a href="#" id="y1" class="btn btn-primary y1" data-submit="modal">Save</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to put a z-index of 1051 on .typeahead to get it to appear above the modal div.

Comment: thanks for the help but it seems that setting the z-index to 1051 is not working . I think that the javascript that i made for the typeahead will not be included in the DOM when i put it inside the modal. Can anyone help me .Please .. i am using codeigniter and twitter bootstrap.

Comment: The typeahead is inserted into the dom outside of the modal area, and is showing underneath the modal. I was able to get it to work by adding .typeahead { z-index: 1051; } into bootstrap.css. This is the same trick that dealt with dropdowns not showing in modals (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/1221)

Comment: +1 They claim the problem has been in the latest version. But its not. I still have the same problem with bootstrap 2.1.1.

Comment: i'm with 2.2.1 and the problem remains

Comment: Since adjusting the z-index alone may not fix it, it might be worth noting to include the overflow-y: visible attribute on .modal-body as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768382/bootstrap-modal-footer-issue

Answer (score 5):

Edit `bootstrap-typeahead.js`:

```
  this.$menu.css({
    top: pos.top + pos.height,
    left: pos.left,
    'z-index': 9999 //maximum z-index
  })
```

Find the highest z-index: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TopZIndex

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I'm running into a version-specific issue that's slightly different, but I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 and no version of z-index was working for me.  I found another solution that ended up working:

```
.modal-body{overflow-y: inherit;}
```

Found at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1078, answer by jgutix

Answer (score 2):

make sure to remove typeahead-append-to-body="true"

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3262

Answer (score 1):

I'm using in my custom css following

```
.modal-body{overflow-y: inherit;}

.modal-open .dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 2050;
}
```

[working example of use](http://www.bootply.com/kj7GJf0b87#)

Answer (score 0):

there is an option to append the drop down to the model

```
 source : function() {},
 select: function (event, ui) {},
 appendTo: "#my-modal"
```