# Bootstrap modal footer hides dropdown menu issue 2

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, z-index

I'm experiencing the same problem issued [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768382/bootstrap-modal-footer-issue). The bootstrap timepicker plugin's dopdown menu is hidden below modal footer.

The workaround suggested in the reference doesn't fit my exigencesm since I want the `overflow-y` value to remain `scroll`.

There must be an alternative solution since this 2 plugins works in 2 different way:

[image: comparation]

Obviously setting `z-index` property doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you recreate this in a jsfiddle or link to your site?

Comment: actually i'm working on localhost and the example in the figure requires too many plugins, css and html to be easily recreated on jsfiddle. 
Anyway, can be recreated downloading just:
bootstrap + 
bootstrap datepicker + 
bootstrap timepicker. 

Popup a modal window and put two input, one datepicker and one timepicker. They will behave differently as shown!

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have `position` declaration set on all divs you are trying to control with `z-index` on. Otherwise `z-index` doesn't know which divs it needs to kept in what order.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set "overflow-y: visible" on .modal-body assuming that you've built the DOM as per bootstrap's docs

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this will help you, but for future users running into this: I actually just found this as well, and it turned out to be an overflow issue.  As it turns out, it's impossible to specify "overflow: auto visible."  See the following post for a more in-depth answer: [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causes-scroll-bar/6433475#6433475)